# Meta's "How to Ask" sidebar is somewhat incorrect

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, meta, sidebar

> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.

This is true for main sites. It is untrue for meta sites - discussion is important and vital. While I'm sure no one reads this on Meta anyway, it shouldn't be wrong.

Comment: I read this line like this: "We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not **just** discussed."

Comment: I agree with @hims. The sentence can easily be read the wrong way, though - I recommend replacing "just" with "simply"